# How can I speed up my C++ compiling?

Tags: visual-c++

Even a simple `cout << "Hello World!";` takes about 25 seconds to compile for me in Visual C++. Same thing in Code::Blocks and every other IDE I've tried. It used to be near instantly. I have no idea why its taking so long.

And its not my processor speed either. I have an i7 2600k at 3.7 GHz, so that shouldn't be a problem. I also have 8GB of RAM.

I have really no idea why this takes so long. Can someone recommend me a solution please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried precompiled headers?

Comment: It'd be nice if you could show the whole of this sample code that's taking so long to compile.  Without any real input, i'm prone to guess that you're including headers you don't need to.  (I've never had "hello world" take more than 5 seconds to compile.)

Comment: Are you using Boost? (Or similar template-heavy code?)

Comment: The entire program is literally an include of iostream, then a main method with a cout inside it. Nothing more.

Comment: @AndrewP: All I can think of is that your CPU has somehow *massively* clocked down... has it? Aside from that, with an i7 and 8 GB of RAM you shouldn't be seeing this happen... is there a lot of disk I/O?

Comment: @AndrewP: That wouldn't compile.  `cout` wouldn't exist if you just included <iostream>.  You'd have to say `std::cout` or `using std::cout;` or `using namespace std;` or something, or include <iostream.h> rather than <iostream>.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't think so. Everything else runs perfectly smoothly. VC++ itself is smooth. I can game on this PC with perfect FPS, but whenever I try to compile C or C++, it slows down. I've compiled massive Java projects in less time than it takes me to compile a simple Hello World in C++.

Comment: When you compile does it look like this?  $ g++ -Wall hello.cc -o hello

Comment: @cHao That's what I mean. std::cout << "Hello World!";

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: In VS?  Probably not.  :)

Comment: @AndrewP: What happens if you try to compile `int main(void) { return 0; }`, with no headers or anything?

Comment: @cHao right! Command line lol...

Comment: @Mehrdad Compiling took 40 seconds. Linking took 25 seconds.

Comment: It helps to see your command line for compiling and linking. Go `"configuration properties->c/c++->command line"` and `"configuration properties->linker->command line"` to look it up.

Comment: @AndrewP: Could you run [Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) and figure out what process is doing heavy disk I/O? I think your disk might be in heavy use (backup software maybe?).

Comment: @WiSaGan Here's what it says for c/c++: "/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\asdf.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue "

Comment: for linker: http://pastebin.com/x4wDEab2

Comment: @Mehrdad The most common programs on that program you gave me were svchost.exe and Skype.

Comment: @AndrewP: Okay, this is plain bizarre... I really have no clue then. >.< I'll let you know if I have any other ideas.

Comment: @Mehrdad What's even more bizarre is that this is a recent occurrence. It was all working fine a few months ago. I have no idea what I changed or screwed up. I might resort to just doing a factory re installation of Windows.

Comment: @AndrewP: Weird... can you try running [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) and posting a screenshot of the View->System Information->Summary tab, after running the program, waiting 30 seconds, and then pressing Compile and waiting 30 seconds into the compilation before taking the screenshot? That'll help us figure out the load on the system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21798/discussion-between-andrewp-and-mehrdad)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0Eoxw.png

Answer (score 0):

Compiling is very I/O bound. Even the fastest Core i7 will still compile slowly if you have an old hard disk.

Degfrag your disk, make sure you have at least 10-20% of your disk space free, or get a faster hard disk. SSDs are amazing for this.

As a benchmark, my retina macbook pro (VS2010 in a VM) can compile 100,000+ line projects (that make heavy use of templates and things like boost) in a few minutes.

Since you have lots of memory, you might get yourself a [RAM disk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) and try that. Don't forget to relocate your system headers & libraries to the ram disk.

Comment: I've got a Western Digital Caviar Black 1TB Hard Disk with about 600GB remaining. Should that be a problem?

Comment: @AndrewP - also, exclude your source, libraries, & headers from your virus scanner's on-access scan function. Visual Studio likes to open files over and over again, and AV programs will be a significant performance drain.

Comment: @Seth I don't have an anti virus. All I have is MalwareBytes. I actually may have a demo of McAfee now that I think of it.